# Using JavaScript promises to display weather and location information

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, google-maps

This is the first time I'm trying to use promises in JavaScript so I'm not sure if I have done it correctly, but it seems to work. The problem is that I have ended up with a "nested `when`" and it doesn't look that great. There probably is a nicer solution out there. I would really appreciate some feedback on how I can improve my code.

I am using the `navigator.geolocation` to get the position and then I'm using two different APIs to get the current weather and the address of the location.

What I would like it to look like would be something like:

```
$.when(getPosition())

.then(getWeather(position),getLocationName(position))

.done(displayWeather);
```

But it doesn't seem to work with two calls in `then()` like you can have in `when()`.

This is my current solution:

```
var displayWeather = function(weatherData, locationData) {

  $('#userLocation').text(locationData.results[3].formatted_address);

  $('#weatherDescription').text(weatherData.currently.temperature);

  $('#temperature').text(weatherData.currently.summary);

}


var getPosition = function() {

  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);

  return deferred.promise();

};


var getWeather = function(position) {

  return $.getJSON('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{APIKEY}/' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '?callback=?')
     .then(function(data) {
        return data;
    });

}


var getLocationName = function(position) {

  return $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&key={APIKEY}')
    .then(function(data) {
        return data;
  });

}


$(document).ready(function() {

  $.when(getPosition())

    .done(function(position) {

      $.when(getWeather(position), getLocationName(position)).done(displayWeather);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.when(getPosition())
```

`$.when` is only used when listening to multiple promises. Since `getPosition` is just one and it already returns a promise, `$.when` isn't required and you can simply chain `then` to `getPosition()`.

```
var getWeather = function(position) {

  return $.getJSON('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{APIKEY}/' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '?callback=?')
     .then(function(data) {
        return data;
    });

}


var getLocationName = function(position) {

  return $.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&key={APIKEY}')
    .then(function(data) {
        return data;
  });

}
```

Attaching `then` which just returns the resolved data `data` is unnecessary. `$.getJSON` already returns a promise-like object that resolves to `data`. Any `then` attached to it will get `data` in the same way this `then` receives it.

Additionally, suggesting you use `then` instead of the jQuery-specific `done`. `then` is standard, and allows you to easily move over to the standard Promises.

I usually recommend pushing off the "flow logic" of promises to the caller instead of spreading it across different functions. This allows you to easily write functions as promise-returning operations while keeping all the "flow logic" in one place.

On other stuff, suggesting you move the url into a variable. This keeps your AJAX operation short and free from the string concatenation madness. A;so recommending using named function instead of function expressions. They're easier to debug as their names appear in the stack trace.

Your code could be simplified into:

```
function getPosition () {

  return $.Deferred(function(deferred){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
  }).promise();

};


function getWeather (position) {
  var url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/{APIKEY}/' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '?callback=?'
  return $.getJSON(url);
}


function getLocationName (position) {
  var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude + '&key={APIKEY}';
  return $.getJSON(url);
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  getPosition().then(function(position){

    return $.when(getWeather(position), getLocationName(position));

  }).then(function(weatherData, locationData){

    $('#userLocation').text(locationData.results[3].formatted_address);
    $('#weatherDescription').text(weatherData.currently.temperature);
    $('#temperature').text(weatherData.currently.summary);

  });

});
```

If you can write using ES6, the code becomes simpler and you can drop the jQuery dependency for the data gathering functions. ES6 now has [native promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as well as [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and modern browsers have [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). This reduces jQuery footprint to only the DOM-interacting operations.

```
function getPosition() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject));
};


function getWeather(position) {
  const url = 'https://api.forecast.io/forecast/${APIKEY}/${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}?callback=?';
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}


function getLocationName(position) {
  const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${position.coords.latitude},${position.coords.longitude}&key=${APIKEY}';
  return fetch(url).then(response => response.json());
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  getPosition()
    .then(position => Promise.all(getWeather(position), getLocationName(position)))
    .then(function(data){
      const weatherData = data[0];
      const locationData = data[1];

      $('#userLocation').text(locationData.results[3].formatted_address);
      $('#weatherDescription').text(weatherData.currently.temperature);
      $('#temperature').text(weatherData.currently.summary);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! One thing that didn't work for me  was to remove the `then` after the `$.getJSON`like you suggested. The `weatherData`and `locationData`is then an array instead of a json object. I will definitely try to write it using ES6 instead though. Looks a lot nicer! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use native promises...  It took me some experimenting to get used to the new javascript features like destructuring, template strings, `.reduce`, and promises, but I like how the code looks...

You can return a `Promise` from getPosition:

```
var getPosition = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject))
```

`$.getJSON` result can be treated like a promise.  So `getWeather` can take `coords` and destructure into `latitude` and `longitude` right in the argument list, then using template strings you can just return `$.getJSON()`

```
var getWeather = ({ latitude, longitude }) =>
    $.getJSON(`https://api.forecast.io/forecast/${FORECAST_API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}?callback=?`);
```

You can call `getPosition()` and call `Promise.all()` with promises to get the weather and location data at the same time.  You can modify the value you return from `.then()` or return another promise from it.  So what I do here is convert the result of `getWeather()` into an object with a `weather` property with the result, same for `location`, then use `.reduce()` on `Promise.all` waiting on those two promises, then `Object.assign()` to merge all those results into one object like `{ position: {}, weather: {}, location: {} }`

```
$(() => {
  getPosition()
  .then(position =>
    Promise.all([
      getWeather(position.coords).then(weather => ({ weather })),
      getLocation(position.coords).then(location => ({ location }))
    ]).then(all => all.reduce((acc, val) => Object.assign(acc, val), { position }))
  )
  .then(data => {
      console.log('data:', data);
      displayWeather(data.weather, data.location);
  })
  .catch(err => alert('ERROR!\r\n' + JSON.stringify(err)))
})
```

So `Promise.all()` ends up with an array that looks like this (`...` is the data from the services):

```
[{weather:{...}, {location:{...}}]
```

Reduce starts with the accumulator (`acc`) as `{postion:{...}}` and operates on each element in that array calling Object.assign with the accumulator and the array value, returning the result with merged properties.

The `Promise.all()` could be changed to use the array indices with the raw results and it looks cleaner, but I like to avoid accidentally using the wrong index for results.  Also you can easily just add another ajax call without changing the `then`...

```
Promise.all([
  getWeather(position.coords),
  getLocation(position.coords)
]).then(all => ({
  weather: all[0],
  location: all[1],
  position
}))
```

I inserted the code as a snippet, but I can't seem to enable location running it.  It works [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/v8z7bpyr/1/) though if you set the api keys...

```js
let FORECAST_API_KEY = 'GET YOUR OWN';
// https://darksky.net/dev/account
let GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'GET YOUR OWN';
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

var displayWeather = function(weatherData, locationData) {
  $('#userLocation').text(locationData.results[3].formatted_address);
  $('#weatherDescription').text(weatherData.currently.summary);
  $('#temperature').text(weatherData.currently.temperature);
}

var getPosition = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
});

var getWeather = ({ latitude,longitude }) => {
  return $.getJSON(`https://api.forecast.io/forecast/${FORECAST_API_KEY}/${latitude},${longitude}?callback=?`);
}

var getLocation = ({latitude, longitude }) => {
  return $.getJSON(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`)
}


$(() => {
  getPosition()
  .then(position =>
    Promise.all([
      getWeather(position.coords).then(weather => ({ weather })),
      getLocation(position.coords).then(location => ({ location }))
    ]).then(all => all.reduce((acc, val) => Object.assign(acc, val), { position }))
  )
  .then(data => {
      console.log('data:', data);
      displayWeather(data.weather, data.location);
  })
  .catch(err => alert('ERROR!\r\n' + JSON.stringify(err)))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
Replace <a href="https://darksky.net/dev/account">forecast.io</a> and
<a href="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key">google</a> api keys with your own!
</p>
<p><span id="userLocation">Loading...</span></p>
<p><span id="weatherDescription">Loading...</span></p>
<p><span id="temperature">Loading...</span></p>
```

Comment: This is a very clean and modern way of doing things. Also, one may look at `forkJoin()` as an option.